# Deploy Python virtualenv on no internet machine with different system

Tags: python, virtualenv, redhat

I need to deploy python application to a no internet server.

I have created a virtual environment on my host machine which uses Ubuntu. This contains python script with a variety of non-standard libraries. I have used option `--relocatable` to make the links relative.

I have copied over the environment to my client machine which uses RedHat and has no access to the internet.

After activating it using source `my_project/bin/activate` the environment does not seem to be working - the python used is standard system one and the libraries don't work.

How can the virtual environment be deployed on a different server?

**Edit:** this is normally done through the creation of `requirement.txt` file and then using pip to install the libraries on the target machine, however in this case it's not possible as the machine is offline.

Comment: How are you calling/invoking the main script ?

Comment: After activating the env with `source my_project/bin/activate`,`python main.py`

Comment: Have you, by chance, considered using Docker for these types of applications?

Comment: Hmm, Can you post the error? It may be a system dependency that is not included on the new system (Similar to how you must include `.so` files when deploying certain python code in the AWS lambda environment)

Comment: The error is `ImportError: no module named 'requests'`. This appears to be because the virtualenv does not recognise the python and the libraries that are included inside it. I have considered using Docker to deploy the environment, however looking for a non-commercial solution.

Comment: Docker Community-Edition is opensource. RHEL maintains their own version of Docker that you can Yum install (after enabling an extras yum repo), or you can install the CentOS version. In either case, it would resolve any potential dependency issues you're currently running into, especially with system-specific libraries.

Comment: In essence, copying/pasting a virtualenv between two different flavors of Linux will raise issues.

It might be simpler just doing a pip download of all your requirements.txt file, copying all the .whl/tar python libraries over to RHEL, and then executing local pip installs of those files in a virtualenv now created on your RHEL box.

Comment: Yes, tried copying .whl/tar files from Ubuntu to RHEL, however this has not worked with some libraries. Could possibly set up RHEL vagrant box and download them there but it seems like a lot of effort. Will give Docker a go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone dealing with the same problem:
The quickest way for me was to:

1. Create a VirtualBox with the target system on the internet machine
2. Download wheel files using `pip download`
3. Migrate to the target machine
4. Install with `pip install --no-index --find-links pip_libs/ requests`

Answer (score 0):

What error is shown when u try to activate it, Make sure the python version and environment PATH are consistent with the ones on the previous system.

Comment: No errors when activating - I can get to the env ok. After I run the script with `python main.py` I'm getting `ImportError: No module named`. 
Also checking `python --version` shows python path of the system NOT the virtualenv

Comment: try running `pip freeze` to see modules that are installed

Comment: `pip freeze` shows me system libraries, not the ones I included in the virtualenv

Comment: if ur virtual env is activated it shouldn't do that

Comment: Yes, got `requirements.txt` in the same folder as the python script. It doesn't look like the activation worked, even though I get (envName) in front of the bash

Comment: Try running `pip install -r requirements.txt` and see what happens